# C preprocessor problem in KEIL

Tags: keil

Here is my code:

```
#define A         16777216.0  
#define B         30.0 
#define C         6990.51 
#define D         1.0
#define Pulse_relation_ThetaAZ     (A*B)/(360.0*C) 

#define StopFreqAZAUX            (((D*1.0*Pulse_relation_ThetaAZ))/(D*1.0))*50.0+52

printf("%ld",StopFreqAZAUX);
```

This code be compiled by Keil but the value of StopFreqAZAUX is strange. what is my mistake?

Edited: The value of StopFreqAZAUX is number between 100 to 500 with a float number for example 100.5, I convert to integer to remove floating part ( for example 100). But the value of StopFreqAZAUX is so high (for example 24*e8 or ...)

Comment: How strange is it?  What values did you expect, and what value did you get? (The more information you provide, the better the chances of a usefull response.)  I think StopFreqAZAUX will be a float - you are printing a long int.

Comment: @PeterBennett It's actually worse, a double is being put in.

Answer (score 6):

You are telling to print an integer variable but then you pass a float variable for printing. They are not compatible. A good compiler would warn about such things which would alarm you from doing things that emit a warning.

Either cast the float to an integer and then print an integer, or print a float to begin with.

Answer (score 6):

C is very much not strongly typed.

When you say `printf("%ld", foo);`, you are telling the printf function "here is a mess of bits which you should *interpret as an integer*".

You're telling the compiler "Make a string containing `%ld` and shove its address onto the stack.  Then shove `foo` onto the stack.  Then call printf."

Nowhere in that chain is anything that independently tells printf function what type `foo` actually is.  Under the hood, printf is defined something like `int printf(char * format, ...);`  The `...` means you can stick anything on there (search on 'varargs' for more information).

As pointed out, most modern compilers will see that you're using a known library function, they'll interpret the string and they'll flag you if `foo` is the wrong type.  But (A) the compiler will usually just issue a warning, so if you're in the habit of ignoring warnings it won't help, and (B), *most* and *modern* leaves out quite a few compilers, especially ones targeting embedded systems.

Answer (score 2):

The incorrect output of `printf` is expected. It is the result of a mismatch between the format-specifier `%ld` and the argument `StopFreqAZAUX`.

After pre-processing, `StopFreqAZAUX` becomes a constant-literal of type `double`. However, the `%ld` format specifier tells `printf` to retrieve the argument as a `long signed int`. Thus the incorrect output. To fix it, use

```
printf ("%f", StopFreqAZAUX);
```

You may also cast explicitly

```
printf ("%f", (double) StopFreqAZAUX);
```